# Busca no mysql pelo Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer uma verificação se o cpf digitado já existe no banco, estou usando laravel, alguém poderia me ajudar nessa função por favor?

No meu controller busco e listo todos os cpfs do banco:

```
    $cpfduplicado = UsuarioEsic::lists('doc', 'id')->all();
foreach ($cpfduplicado as $cpf)
            if ($cpf == $request->cpf)
                $cpf = 'verdadeiro';
//                return redirect('/Esic/CadastroFisica');
return redirect('/Esic/Sucesso');
```

Não sei muito bem como fazer uma função no javascript para pegar esses dados e setar um custom validity do browser, eu fiz algo assim:

```
$(function cpfdupli(input) {
    $('.btnCadastroo').on('click', function (json){
        if (json.cpf === 'verdadeiro'){
            document.getElementById('cpff');
            input.setCustomValidity('Cpf já existe.');
        } else {
            input.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    });
});
```

Eu sou iniciante no ramo e não sei muito bem como fazer isso funcionar, eu só queria que se o cpf já existisse setasse um CustomValidity no browser e não deixasse ele continuar com o cadastro, se alguém puder me ajudar ou me dar outras formas de como resolver isso eu ficaria muito grato !

Obs: Qualquer dúvida sobre o código estarei disponível para fornecer.

Comment: como o `browser` do cliente não tem acesso ao `MySQL` no seu servidor, o `JavaScript` não irá consultar o `MySQL` (ainda bem), então você terá de fazer uma requisição usando `AJAX/XMLHttpRequest` e como retorno devolva um objeto usando o método `json_encode`.

Comment: Mas  quem faz a consulta ao mysql é o meu controller, eu preciso apenas de jogar a informação do controller para o javascript e então fazer a verificação se o cpf digitado é igual à algum dos cpf's listados pelo controller e então setar uma função do browser.

Comment: O único vinculo entre a sua controller em PHP e a pagina do cliente são as requisições Http (apesar do spaghetti escrito por alguns programadores PHP dá a impressão que o PHP tem algum vinculo com o HTML e o JavaScript), então o meu comentário se mantem.

Comment: Licoln, da uma lida no seguinte link: [Como mudar status com AJAX?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138785/como-mudar-status-com-ajax/138860#138860), tem um passo a passo de como fazer uma requisição `AJAX`, o uso do `json_encode` e como ler o json de retorno e atualizar a pagina do cliente.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, estava no almoço, vou estudar isso aí agora mesmo, obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, não entendi o motivo de você fazer um `LIST` para fazer essa verificação. Você poderia fazer uma query semelhante a isso.

```
$cpfduplicado = UsuarioEsic::where('cpf', $request->cpf)->get();
```

Assim só retorna o CPF caso esteja duplicado.

Depois voce poderia fazer uma verificação se o retorno está vazio ( caso não encontre um cpf igual)

```
if(empty($cpfduplicado)){
  return redirect('/Esic/Sucesso');
}
```

Caso seja `JSON`, voce pode retornar um valor também.
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Me ajudou bastante amigo, ajudou a melhorar meu código, muito obrigado mesmo, como disse, sou um iniciante na área, do jeito que você falou fnciona perfeitamente, no entanto eu preciso que informe ao usuário que o cpf informado já existe, dessa forma, se ele não passar pela verificação eu não consigo fazer um CustomValidity, que é só no javascript e é a única forma que eu conseguir de avisar o usuário e impedir que ele siga com a página sem ter que atualizar ou limpar os campos já digitados....De qualquer forma muito obrigado mesmo, continuo estudando e pesquisando sobre o assunto... :D